# One Apple ID, two devices purchased in different locations. How to manage address on both devices?

Tags: iphone

I am using a single Apple ID on two devices (iPhone 5s purchased in India, and iPad purchased in the US). How can I manage my address on each device?

Also, if I update the address to my Indian address, will it be fine with my current card details?

Thanks & regards.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  I've never had an Apple ID in a different country so I'm confused by your question "How can I manage my address on each device?"  What does this mean?  I would suggest editing your question to include the problems you're having because of this issue.  This will provide better context around your question.

Comment: It would help if you explained your living situation: do you live in India or the US? Do you live there permanently, as opposed to 6 months in one, and 6 months in the other? Why do you need to specify different addresses on each device? Why do you think specifying your Indian address will be a problem with your credit card? Where are you entering these addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Your address in your iCloud account is not required to be in the same country where you purchased an iOS device. Enter the address where you live into your iCloud account.

If you happen to live in India but have your credit card registered in the US, enter your India address as your shipping address, but your US address as your billing address. However, many credit card companies will require some kind of confirmation from you if you ship to an address that isn’t your billing address.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Devices do not matter where they are purchased. Any Apple ID can be linked onto it. You can set the "Apple ID" region to whichever region you are currently residing in with the Card information. There will be no conflicts on your device if you use an US Apple ID.

To answer the question, You can update it to Indian Address. Just make sure you have an Indian Credit Card that can be added to your Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, having moved from one to another country, the country where the credit card is issued in will determine which country's iTunes store you can buy apps or movies or books from.

If you switched stores, you need a valid billing address and credit card from the country you're switching to. You won't be able to download apps, movies or books if they are not available in the new country's store.

For example, there will be apps only available in the India app store but not in the US store and vice versa. You would need to download them first before switching to ensure you'll be able to keep using them.

Before switching country /region in iTunes, you will need to cancel any active iTunes Match subscription. You can switch stores back as long as you have a valid billing address and credit card, and then you will be able to have access again to your purchased apps, movies or books. All other purchases are not transferable.